# React npm "module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)"

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to setup React environment and I am getting two errors when running npm start in command prompt.

First error is "module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)" and second is
"error plugin/preset files are not allowed to export objects only functions".

Any idea how this could be solved? I am new to this whole thing so please try to keep answer simple and steps easy to follow.

Comment: Please tell us a little more about your environment. Are you using webpack, for example? And can you post your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

change your directory and install your app again via this code :

```
npx create-react-app yourAppName
```

then install all dependencies